# How to get time format with hours and minutes from Mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and got problem doing properly the query.

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT datetime ...');
$resultdata['results'] = $query->result_array();

foreach($results as $result)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$result['datetime']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

This code make result of the date in this format: 2015-04-11 02:45:19.
How can I do the result only with HOURS and MINUTES? Thank you.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just use MySQL's [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetime, "%H:%i") as `time` ...
```